# Proof of $P(\mathbf a,\mathbf b)=-\mathbf a\cdot\mathbf b$ in Bell’s original paper

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, bells-inequality

Bell’s original 1964 argument works by comparing a QM prediction with the prediction of a local hidden variable theory. In the notation of Griffith’s version of it in ”Introduction to Quantum Mechanics” where $P(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b})$ is the average value of the product of the spins for a given set of detector orientations given by the unit vectors $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}$, the QM prediction is:

$P(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}) = -\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b}$.

Is there a simple proof of this prediction, suitable for a student at the level of Griffith’s book?

Comment: Preskill's notes, http://www.theory.caltech.edu/~preskill/ph229/notes/chap4_01.pdf,  pg. 14+15.

Answer (score 1):

One route is the one followed in [the notes already linked in the comments](http://www.theory.caltech.edu/~preskill/ph229/notes/chap4_01.pdf). Here is another derivation (though most likely not the one used in Bell's original paper).

We want to compute the expectation value:
$$
  \langle \Psi|
    [(\boldsymbol\sigma\cdot\mathbf a) \otimes
    (\boldsymbol\sigma\cdot\mathbf b)]
  |\Psi\rangle=
  a_i b_j \Psi^\dagger (\sigma_i\otimes\sigma_j)\Psi =
  a_i b_j \bar\Psi_{\alpha\beta} \Psi_{\gamma\delta} (\sigma_i)_{\alpha\gamma}(\sigma_j)_{\beta\delta}.
$$
Now, if $|\Psi\rangle$ is maximally entangled, and in particular is the singlet $|01\rangle-|10\rangle$, then $\Psi_{\alpha\beta}=(-1)^{\alpha}\delta_{\alpha+\beta=0}/\sqrt 2=(iY)_{\alpha\beta}/\sqrt2$, where $Y\equiv\sigma_2$ is the Pauli matrix, and thus
$$
  a_i b_j \bar\Psi_{\alpha\beta} \Psi_{\gamma\delta} (\sigma_i)_{\alpha\gamma}(\sigma_j)_{\beta\delta} =
  \frac12 a_i b_j \operatorname{Tr}(Y\sigma_i Y\sigma_j^T) 
  = -\frac12 a_i b_j  \operatorname{Tr}(\sigma_i\sigma_j)
  = -\mathbf a\cdot\mathbf b,
$$
where we used the identities:
$$Y\sigma_i Y=(-1)^{1+\delta_{i,2}}\sigma_i,
\qquad \sigma_i^T = (-1)^{\delta_{i,2}} \sigma_i.$$

---

More generally, suppose $|\Psi\rangle$ is maximally entangled. That means that $\operatorname{Tr}_B(|\Psi\rangle\!\langle\Psi|)=I/2$, that is, in terms of the matrix elements $\Psi_{12}$, $\Psi_{12}\bar\Psi_{32}=\delta_{13}/2$, or equivalently $\Psi\Psi^\dagger =I/2$.
The general form of $\Psi$ is therefore
$$\sqrt2 \,|\Psi\rangle= |0\rangle\!\langle u| + |1\rangle\!\langle v|,$$
for some pair of orthonormal states $|u\rangle,|v\rangle$, and thus in matrix notation, $\sqrt2\,\Psi=U$, with $U$ the unitary whose rows are (the complex conjugates of) $|u\rangle$ and $|v\rangle$.

Now, any $2\times2$ unitary can be written in terms of Pauli matrices as
$$U=e^{i\theta} (c_0 I + ic_1 X +ic_2 Y + ic_3 Z),$$
for some choice of real parameters $c_0,c_1,c_2,c_3$ that are normalised to one: $(c_0,c_1,c_2,c_3)\in S^3$, and $\theta\in\mathbb R$. We can fix $\theta=0$ without loss of generality here.
Our expectation value then reads
$$
  \langle \Psi|
    [(\boldsymbol\sigma\cdot\mathbf a) \otimes
    (\boldsymbol\sigma\cdot\mathbf b)]
  |\Psi\rangle=
  a_i b_j \bar\Psi_{\alpha\beta} \Psi_{\gamma\delta} (\sigma_i)_{\alpha\gamma}(\sigma_j)_{\beta\delta} \\
  = a_i b_j \operatorname{Tr}(\Psi^\dagger\sigma_i \Psi \sigma_j^T)
  = \frac12 a_i b_j \operatorname{Tr}(U^\dagger\sigma_i U \sigma_j^T).
$$
There is then always an orthogonal transformation $B_{ij}$ such that $U^\dagger \sigma_i U=B_{ji}\sigma_i$, using which we conclude that
$$\frac12 a_i b_j B_{ji} \operatorname{Tr}(\sigma_i \sigma_j^T)
= \frac12 \mathbf b \tilde B \mathbf a,$$
where $\tilde B$ differs from $B$ only in the sign of its second row.

Answer (score 1):

Let me make an attempt at a high-level argument:

We want to compute 
$$
\langle\Psi^-\vert(\vec a \cdot\vec\sigma)\otimes(\vec b\cdot\vec \sigma)\vert\Psi^-\rangle\ .\tag{*}
$$
with $\vert\Psi^-\rangle$ the singlet state.

First, since $\vert\Psi^-\rangle$ is invariant under rotations, (*) can only depend on the relative angle between $\vec a$ and $\vec b$, that is, $\vec a \cdot \vec b$.  In addition, (*) is linear in $\vec a$ and $\vec b$.  Thus, it must be proportional to $\vec a\cdot \vec b$. The proportionality constant can now be determined by picking a specific case (such as parallel $\vec a$ and $\vec b$).